# Restoring missing icons

Tags: windows-7

My desktop was send in for repairs. I have restored backup but icons are missing. I’m running Windows 7. How do I get my icons back? I Tried right clicking the Desktop > View > Show desktop icons with no luck.

Comment: Are you sure the operating system wasn’t reinstalled? Are you logging into the correct profile? We need more information on what the repair was, the icons should simply be there, unless they were deleted by someone

Comment: What icons are not there? Is the software, or the files they point to still present or installed?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if that is obvious/basic but the icons displayed on your desktop are usually files/folders located in `c:\Users\<your_user_name>\Desktop`. So if you browse to that directory (e.g. in Windows Explorer) there are no files in that folder, you have to find those files in your backups and copy them there.